# Laravel: When validation fails, is possible to have the {{ old('file') }} value? If so, how?

Tags: php, laravel

You know, when you're validating and validation fails, it goes back to the offending page. In a text input you do

```
<input type="text" name="x" value="{{ old('x') }}">
```

so the user doesn't have to type everything again, and that's great, specially on textareas.

How can I do the same thing in `type="file"` fields?

```
<input type="file" name="y" value="{{ old('y') }}">
```

of course doesn't work.

Comment: not really possible. You could process the file anyway and do some useless stuff to re populate it with ajax, Really not worth it though

Comment: :( yeah, if I have to program it to work, is not worthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no possible way for that.
if it is vital for you, do the validation using ajax call and if it returns ok, submit your form with file input.

Comment: Nah... like "vital", nah... but it would be convenient, specially because this specific form can upload up to 4 files